# Change init scripts priority

Tags: linux, init-script, priority

I'm running a raspbian (based on debian). I want to change the priority of the init services so the very first script which is run by init is one made for me. How can I do it?

On runlevel S I have 3 scripts with priortity 01: hostname.sh, fake-hwclock and mountkernfs.sh. If I just put my script on runlevel S with priority 01, it's not the first one to be executed. I have tried to change the priortiy of all these scripts to 02 using (for example in the case of mountkernfs.sh)

```
sudo update-rc.d -f mountkernfs.sh remove
sudo update-rc.d mountkernfs.sh start 02 S
```

The first command effectively removes the script from /etc/rcS.d. The second command puts again mountkernfs.sh with priority 01.

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The init scripts on /etc/init.d/ specify some information on it's LSB header, which in essence are just some lines at the beginning of the script. The field  "Required-Start" of some script allows you to specify services that must be initialized before this script. `insserv` automatically add init scripts regarding LSB header.

Therefore, to solve the problem:

- Name your script "X" using "Provides" field on LSB header.
- Add the runlevels where the script has to be started and stopped using "Default-Start" and "Default-Stop" fields respectively on LSB header.
- Set "X" to the field "Required-Start" on the LSB header of the scripts with priority 01: hostname.sh, fake-hwclock and mountkernfs.sh.
- Add the service using `sudo insserv name_of_your_script_file` (not the name you give to "Provides" field)

This moves all the necessary script priorities of the involved scripts to match the dependencies. In my case:

- S01X.sh
- S02mountkernfs.sh
- S02hostname.sh
- S02fake-hwclock
- S03udev

Source: http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot

.